# search for an element inside an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

hello I am trying to search for a number in an array and if the num was found I want to print the item was found, if not I want to print that the number was not found

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Array = new int[10];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements:");
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++) 
                Array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter thevalue to search:");
            int v = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int j = 0; j < Array.Length; j++) {
                if (Array[j] == v)
                    Console.WriteLine("The item was found at location:" + j);
                
            }
            

            Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a flag to record that the item was found. If the flag is *not* set when the loop has finished, then you know that the item was not found.

Comment: ...and `break;` out of the loop once you find the number.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using a `for` loop for searching, you could just use the [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.) method.

Comment: how can i add a break statement

Comment: i want to print the item was not found if it's not found

Comment: You should not name a variable `Array` as it conflicts with `System.Array`. Use lowercase for variables as it is recommended.

Comment: Hint: the `break;` statement exits a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.IndexOf()` which will return the index of the item you are looking for, otherwise it will return -1.

Note: In this case `Array` is the object type, not the variable name. So you would need to rename your variables. Something like this:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] input = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) 
            input[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value to search:");
        int item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int index = Array.IndexOf(input, item);
    
        string message = index == -1
            ? "The item is not in the array"
            : "The item was found at index: " + index;
    
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the overload from linq `Select` that returns you every value and it's index work with that:

```
int[] Array = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine ("Enter the array elements:");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
  Array[i] = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
Console.WriteLine ("Enter thevalue to search:");
int v = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

var result = Array
  // convert it to tupple containing x (the value) and index (position in array)
  .Select ((x, index) => (x, index))
  // Search for the x (the value) that is equal to v
  .Where (tupple => tupple.x == v)
  .ToList ();
if (result.Any ())
{
  // There could be more than one item in the array that contains v so we build a comma separated list of all indexes
  var indexes = string.Join (", ", result.Select (tupple => tupple.index));
  Console.WriteLine ($"The item was found at location(s): {indexes}");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine ("The item was not found");
}

Console.ReadLine ();
```